# Amazon S3 cannot call API because of no such host error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, bucket

I am attempting to build an Amazon S3 client in GoLang but I am having trouble making API calls. I'm receiving an error that says "no such host" but I am positive the credentials I'm providing are correct.

**Defining a struct to hold the client**

```
// the Client struct holding the client itself as  well as the bucket.
type S3Client struct {
    S3clientObject s3.S3
    bucket string
}

// Initialize the client
func CreateS3Client() S3Client{
     S3clientCreate := S3Client{S3clientObject: Connect(), bucket: GetS3Bucket()}
     if (!CheckBuckets(S3clientCreate)) {
         exitErrorf("Bucket does not exist, try again.")
     }
     return S3clientCreate
}
```

**Connecting to the bucket**

```
func Connect() s3.S3{
    // Initialize a session
    
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("myCredentials", "myCreds", ""),
        Endpoint:    aws.String("myDomain"),
        Region:      aws.String("myRegion"),
    },
    )
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to use credentials, %v", err)
    }
    // Create S3 service client
    svc := s3.New(sess)
    return *svc
}
```

At this point, I am able to establish a connection and use the ListBuckets functionality to receive a list of all the buckets (like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListBuckets)

**When I try to call the GetObject API, it tells me it cannot find the host**

```
// Gets an object from the bucket
func Get(client S3Client, key string) interface{} {
    
    // golang does not support "default values" so I used a nil (same as null)
    if (key == "") {
        return nil
    }

    svc := client.S3clientObject
    input := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("myBucket"),
        Key: aws.String("myPathKey"),
    }

    result, err := svc.GetObject(input)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case s3.ErrCodeNoSuchKey:
                fmt.Println(s3.ErrCodeNoSuchKey, aerr.Error())
            case s3.ErrCodeInvalidObjectState:
                fmt.Println(s3.ErrCodeInvalidObjectState, aerr.Error())
            default:
                fmt.Println(aerr.Error())  
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

This returns:

```
dial tcp: lookup "hostname": no such host
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening, because I am able to successfully make a connection to the bucket, and list them out using ListBuckets, but when using another API call, it fails to find the host. Is there something wrong with my code? Is there another configuration that I forgot about?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated as I'm somewhat new to using GoLang and S3.

Comment: You can follow this example: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/example/service/s3/getObjectWithProgress/getObjectWithProgress.go

Code seems ok and it's difficult to judge as many things could be wrong. I think you should use a debugger to narrow down the problem. Or provide more details to us

Comment: @SaurabhNigam What more details would you need? I unfortunately cannot share credentials or hostnames but I have triple checked that they are accurate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the issue was with the bucket name. All I did to resolve this was put a "/" in front of the bucket name when creating it and it worked.

Comment: Just another reason to hate AWS  (╯° °）╯︵ ┻━┻ How did you figure this out, did you find documentation?